# Building a bulk email messaging solution

Tags: email, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I code with c sharp asp.net. I have a business app. I need to send emails in large mass. But when I look at the existing email marketing solutions using them would increase my cost overhead. I intend sending as much as 10 million emails in a month. 
So am building a bulk messaging solution.  Based on my research I was advised to use System.Net.Mail API ?.  I have looked into it, It looks prity nice and simple.

My question goes does is since am using asp.net, do I need to install mvc.mailer to do the job
 or I just use System.Net.Mail.

Second question, I intend hosting my app on a cloud server, would cloud server give me unlimited emails which would not be barred even if I send like 200 million mails,

Or am I suppose to host this solution on a dedicated server ?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Don't try to do this yourself. You'll get blacklisted in less than a day. Maybe an hour.

Comment: Sending the messages is probably not all that difficult. Actually getting your messages delivered to the inbox off every intended recipient is a much bigger challenge and typically worth paying for. - The relative merits of one library or the other are probably better discussed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok, thanks I have been reading on spamming policies. I am fully aware of it. But cant I develop this. It was someone who developed the mailchimps and the others. I just feel that it can be done.

Comment: what if I am using a dedicated server. Would I still be blacklisted. We decided to do this, cause when we tink of the all round cost of sending like 100 million emails in a month. It is what researching and   creating a bulk messaging to handle this. The overhead cost is really high.

Comment: Keep doing some research, or else you'll waste time coding a solution, and then get banned by your hosting provider or ISP.

Comment: yes I am doing research. I know that the said subject is really delicate and needs to be handled with care

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be to use a Linux VPS like linode.com or any other low cost service with a reasonable hardware setup but there's a lot of steps involved. Here's an overview:

1. Install Ubuntu or CentOS or any other Linux distribution that you feel confortable with or use the standard of your VPS host
2. Install Postfix as SMTP server and configure it to accept only connections from your application server (avoids spammers to use your server for their mails)
3. On your application use any API or library to connect and send email messages through your postfix server
4. Setup your mail server properly on your DNS server to avoid having your messagens going to spam/rejected automatically

I had a similar problem and using a shared VPS i could send as much as 2k newsletters per minute. That's more than 2.8 million a day. I'm sure you can do better using better hardware and network.